# Boot failing due to SMART error status?

Tags: raid, software-raid, ubuntu-18.04, bios

I have an Asus server that was refusing to boot, reporting:

```
SATA Port 1 : Hitachi HDS721010DLE630
S.M.A.R.T status bad, backup and replace
```

So I went into the bios, disabled "SMART status check", allowing me to boot normally into Ubuntu 18. I have a software RAID1 setup, so I checked `/proc/mdstat` which reports:

```
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md1 : active raid1 sda2[1] sdb2[2]
      968948600 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[1] sdb1[2]
      7810036 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

or in other words, no RAID error.

Why is my bios detecting a RAID error? It feels wrong to disable RAID status check, but if it's a false positive, I don't know what else I should do.

Comment: SMART status being bad could be related to bad sectors on one of your hard drives. I'd highly recommend running a disk scanning utility to see if any drive has problems, as smart status bad could mean one of your drive is nearing it's end of life.

Comment: @Dexirian Then wouldn't mdstat report a RAID degradation? At what point does a bad SMART status become a RAID failure?

Comment: If bad smart checks are left unchecked (no pun intended), and the disk does have problems, eventually you'll turn up a RAID failure. smartmontools might be able to give you some insight : https://alternativeto.net/software/smartmontools/